# The existence of inequalities between the sum of a sequence and the sum of its members

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Let $I$ denote some finite subset of $M := \{m, m+1, \cdots \}$, i.e., $I$ is the index of some points of $(a_n)_{n=m}^\infty$.

Does there exist a real number $r$ such that for any valid $I$, $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n > r$ and $\sum_{i \in I}a_i \leq r$?

It seems that if $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ is finite, let's denoted by $S$. Such a $r$ can be written as $S - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a positive real number. Assume that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\sum_{i \in I} a_i > S - \epsilon$, which means that the sequence $(\sum_{i \in I}a_i)_{I \in 2^M}$ is bounded by $S$. Then how to do next?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since each $a_n$ is positive you have $$\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n = \sup_I \sum_{i \in I} a_i$$ where the supremum is taken over all finite subsets $I$ of $M$. This is a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem for series.